# getting Status 0 while loading the file

Tags: javascript, xml, status

I am just novice and learning AJAX from some tutorials. After the end of video, when I loaded the files given in tutorial(without making any changes) I got xml status 0, and some consoles error. Here is the code

```
window.onload = makeRequest;
var xhr = false;

function makeRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) { }
        }
    }

    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = showState;
        xhr.open("GET", "colors.xml", true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("updateArea").innerHTML = "Sorry, but I couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest";
    }
}

function showState() {
    var currMsg = document.getElementById("updateArea").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("updateArea").innerHTML = currMsg + "<p>The current state is " + xhr.readyState + " and the status is " + xhr.status + "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Did you try hosting this code on any server?

Comment: *"and some consoles error"* Has it occurred to you that the error is related to your problem? Posting the error message might enable us to help you!